# Is there a way to convert from System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement to mshtml.IHTMLElemenet3?

Tags: c#, .net, html, vb.net

Is there a way to convert from System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement to mshtml.IHTMLElemenet3?

--edit after answer accepted --
This is what the code would look like.

```
HtmlElement myElement = getElementByID(id);
IHTMLElement3 h3 = (IHTMLElement3) myElement.DomElement;
```

Thanks @korchev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast the DomElement property to mshtml.IHTMLElement3